# How can I permanently save aufio files in Android?

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences, android-mediaplayer, android-mediarecorder

I want to save .3gp files permanently in Android. I wrote methods for this but if I close the app and restart it, my app crashes when I try to play my recorded sound.

Here's my record-method(note that I have to code the path this way since API 29):

```
 public void startRecording(){
    try {
        f = new File(getExternalFilesDir(null), "recorded.3gp");

        mediaRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);;
        mediaRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
        mediaRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.AMR_NB);


        mediaRecorder.setOutputFile(f.getAbsolutePath());
        mediaRecorder.prepare();
        mediaRecorder.start();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

My stop-method:

```
 public void stopRecording(){
    try {
        mediaRecorder.stop();
        mediaRecorder.release();
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

My play-method:

```
public void playRecord(){
    MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
    try {
        mediaPlayer.setDataSource(f.getAbsolutePath());
        mediaPlayer.prepare();
        mediaPlayer.start();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

In which folder can I find these recordings? I wanna get access later from app.

Thx

Comment: Well they should be in getExternalFilesDir(null) as that is the folder where you saved them.

Comment: If your app crashes you did not catch an exception that was thrown. Have a look in the logcat.

Comment: But how can I get access to them if I restart the App? Is this the normal way to save it permanently?

Comment: `mediaPlayer.setDataSource(f.getAbsolutePath())` You should include the code where you assign `f` a value. The used path.

Comment: Saving to getExternalFilesDir is permanent until the app is uninstalled.

Comment: blackapps -> In line 3 of the startRecording() method you can see  f = new File(getExternalFilesDir(null), "recorded.3gp");

Comment: Yes i have seen that. But that is local to that function. And you have restarted the app. So `f` has to be initialized again. You are not doing that in your code. You have a NullPointerException which lets your apo crash. But you did not inform us.

Comment: I wrote "public File f;" directly in MainActivity class, do I have to write this in onCreate method? Here's my Exception:  java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String java.io.File.getAbsolutePath()' on a null object reference

Comment: Remove it. You should have `File f = new File(getExternalFilesDir(null), "recorded.3gp");`  in both of your functions.

Comment: Thank you, works fine. But if I start the recording funktion twice the app crashes again. I think it does because i try to create a file that already exists. But i have no chance to delete the old file because it will now created in this method...

Comment: Only the media recorder creates files with that name. You could check if the name is already in use and then generate the next name. Then start the recorder with it.  If your app crashes an exception was thrown that you did not catch. Use logcat to find out which.

Comment: But how can I check if the name is already used?

Comment: Use File:exists().